# Magento cron schedule created_at time is always 2 hours behind from server time

Tags: php, magento

Magento cron schedule created_at time is always 2 hours behind from server time. Mysql server time, Magento Time and PHP time are same. But the magento cron job created_at time is always 2 hours behind. What could be the reason ?

Comment: created_at time being timestamped as UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Its not just your Cron schedule that defines when the cron job is created or runs but it also depends on the settings defined in Magento under Admin => system => configuration => system => ‘Cron (Scheduled Tasks)’ . Ideally, you should use the below settings to ensure that the Cron runs correctly :

Generate schedules every: 60
Schedule ahead for: 1
Missed if not run within: 60
History cleanup every: 120
Success history lifetime: 120
Failure history lifetime: 120

Also, ensure that you run the Cron every 15 minutes for best results. That shall ensure that it doesn't coincide with other Cron services.

Comment: Thanks, let me try and see.